# Mahabharat eyewitness

Tags: mahabharata, kurukshetra

In the Mahabharat there was a character Barbrik. 
Can anyone share more details on this?
I understand that he had the powers to end the Mahabharat with 3 arrows.

Comment: Barbarik is name of that person. Now we know him as khatushayam,right?

Comment: Yap... thats correct. its Barbarik and not Palpreek.....

Answer (score 7):

Barbrik was the grandson of Bheem. He, by the virtue of his Worship of Lord Shiva, had 3 arrows in his quiver. He had the blessings that he could finish anything with his 3 arrows. Since, the pandavas were weaker in terms of army size, Barbrik had promised his mother that he would fight from the losing side, thinking that the Pandavas would be losing and would need his help.

When Krishna got to know about him, he challenged Barbrik to burn all the leaves of a tree. While Barbrik was doing this, Krishna hid one leaf under his foot. Barbrik's arrow marked all the leaves and then started pricking Krishna's foot. Knowing his strength and his resolve to fight from the losing side, Krishna convinced Barbrik to cut his head and placed it on the same tree so that he could witness the entire battle as per his last wish.

At the end of the war, Pandavas were discussing who had the most impact and Krishna suggested them to check with Barbrik. Barbrik said, he could only see one person fighting all the while and that was lord Krishna.

Answer (score 2):

Barbarika or Barbarik is the son of [Ghatotkacha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghatotkacha) and [Ahilawati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahilawati)

Barbarika was originally a yaksha, and was reborn as a man. He was bound by his principle of always fighting on the losing side, which led him to stand witness to the battle of Mahabharata without taking part in it .

Ghatotkacha has been himself the son of great Bhima and Hidimba.

Lord Shiva has granted three infallible arrows to Barbarik, which had the power to conquer the whole world. Agni god has bestowed him with a bow.

Before the Mahabharata war began, Lord Krishna queried the warriors how many days he would take to finish Mahabharat war alone. Bhishma answered that he would take 20 days to finish the war. Dronacharya said 25 days. Karna  said he would take 24 days. Arjuna told Krishna it would take 28 days for him to complete the battle.

Then he asked Barbari as how many days he would require? Barbari replied that he would take only a minute. Krishna baited Barbarika by mocking him for going to the great battle with only three arrows. In reply, Barbari proved to Krishna that he indeed would require only a minute.

Krishna then asks the boy whom he would favour in the war of Mahabharat. Barbarika reveals that he intends to fight from the weaker side. As Pandavas have only seven Akshouhini army, when compared to Kauravas eleven, he considers that Pandavas are weak and hence wants to support them. Krishna explains  consequence of his word to Barbari’s mother.

Krishna tells that whichever side Barbari supports will only make the other side weak due to his power. Nobody has the skill or power to defeat him. Hence, he is forced to support the other side that has become weaker due to his word to his mother. Thus, in an actual war, he will keep switching between the two sides, thereby destroying the entire army of both sides and eventually only he survives. Subsequently, none of the side is victorious as he will be the only lone survivor. Hence, Krishna avoids his participation from the war by seeking his head in charity.

He is also known as Teen Baandhari and Khatu Shyamji. He is one of the persons who saw Shri Krishna’s vishwaroopa form.

that's little about barbarik,.